# How can I add OTP expiry time in Next.js with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

how to add OTP expire time in next js firebase

i search on firebase docs but i could'n find any solution about my problem

this is my code for sent otp

```
const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

const phoneNumber = "+91" + mobile_no;

signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier).then((confirmationResult) => {
    // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
    // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
    window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    console.log("OTP SENT SUCCESSFULLY...");
    // ...
}).catch((error) => {
    // Error; SMS not sent
       
    console.log("OTP NOT SENT BECAUSE OF ===>", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated information:

Password reset: The expiration time for password reset links is set to 1 hour.

Email change notice: The expiration time for email change notice links is set to 6 hours.

Email verification: The expiration time for email verification links is set to 3 days.

Email link sign-in: The expiration time for email link sign-in links is set to 6 hours.

OTP code (phone auth): The expiration time for OTP codes used in phone authentication is set to 15 minutes.

Please note that these expiration times are predefined and cannot be modified. This information has been verified with the Firebase team support